# Java Regex getting parts of file

Tags: regex, java-8

I have a .sql file that I am parsing but failing in getting the matches I need. I should have two matches of multi-lines comments. Any help would be appreciated.

1. the beginning statements to SET
2. the closing statements to SET

I have tried this (https://regex101.com/) but it won't get all the comments. At best it just grabs the last 2 lines of each section I am expecting.

```
^\/\*![0-9]{0,10}.+?\s.*\*\/;\n^\s*$\n^--
```

Expecting this to be match 1

```
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Expecting this to be match 2

```
**/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;**
```

File I am parsing:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.32, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: mysql-0    Database: customdb
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.39-log
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `custom_company`
--

INSERT  IGNORE INTO `custom_company` VALUES ('TESTCOMPANYGMBH','TESTCOMPANY','Test Company',100000001);

INSERT  IGNORE INTO `version_custom` VALUES ('2022-09-19 04:02:05',NULL,20);
INSERT  IGNORE INTO `version_custom` VALUES ('2022-09-19 04:02:05',NULL,21);
**/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;**

-- Dump completed on 2023-03-02  3:18:10
```

Comment: The trailing `\n^\s*$\n^--` in your regex seems weird, since no `--` ever shows up in any of your two "expecting" samples. Do you want your pattern to match *each line* in those sections or *the whole thing*?

Comment: Is `(?:^\/\*![0-9]{0,10} .*? \*\/;\n+)+--` what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi @JoachimSauer thanks so much this is what I was looking for. It gives me the two matches I was looking for.

I used "\n^\s*$\n^--" to make sure I was getting all the lines based on a blank line and the -- on a new line. I was afraid that the second match would be split into two matches based on the empty line. but somehow you took care of that in your example. Do you maybe have a link that shows me why your line works? I need to better understand REGEX I know enough to be very dangerous.

Comment: regex101 actually does a fairly good job at explaining what each part of a regex means. Beyond that it's really just "simple logic" to figure out how they interact (together with some basic understanding of regex, of course). Unfortunately I don't know of a simple resource that explains that well (though I'm sure they exist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the first part in Java, you could use

```
(?:^/\*!\d{0,10}\h.*\h\*/;\R+)+(?=--$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part
- `^` Start of string

  - `/\*!\d{0,10}`
  - `\h.*\h\*/;` Match a horizontal whitespace char, the rest of the line and then a horizontal whitspace char followed by `*/;`
- `\R+` Match 1 or more time a unicode newline sequence
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat it 1 or more times to match all lines
- `(?=--$)` Positive lookahead, assert `--` followed by the end of the string to the right

In Java:

```
String regex = "(?:^/\\*!\\d{0,10}\\h.*\\h\\*/;\\R+)+--$";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RWe9v9/1)

---

To match both parts, you could use an alternation `|` to match 2 different patterns where the second pattern starts with `**/*` and ends with `;**` and in between matches the same line format as previous pattern or an empty string:

```
(?:^/\*!\d{0,10}\h.*\h\*/;\R+)+(?=--$)|^\*\*/\*!\d{0,10}\h.*\h\*/;(?:\R(?:/\*!\d{0,10}\h.*\h\*/;)?)*\R/\**!\d{0,10}\h.*\h\*/;\*\*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F620Hu/1)

In Java:

```
String regex = "(?:^/\\*!\\d{0,10}\\h.*\\h\\*/;\\R+)+(?=--$)|^\\*\\*/\\*!\\d{0,10}\\h.*\\h\\*/;(?:\\R(?:/\\*!\\d{0,10}\\h.*\\h\\*/;)?)*\\R/\\**!\\d{0,10}\\h.*\\h\\*/;\\*\\*$";
```